# netcfg error in Arch: 'Profile doesn't exist'

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networking

To setup automatic wireless connection in Arch, I configured `netcfg` as directed in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netcfg). When I try:

```
[root@geckko ~]# netcfg adsl
```

it gives an error:

```
 > Profile "adsl" does not exist
```

The profile does exist as I have checked:

```
[root@geckko network.d]# ls
adsl  examples  hooks  interfaces
```

I googled and found [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=82773) in the Arch forum but I'm pretty sure I haven't made the same mistake the author of that thread has made. How can I solve this issue?

Here's the profile:

```
CONNECTION='wireless'
DESCRIPTION='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
INTERFACE='wlan0'
SECURITY='wpa'
ESSID='essid'
KEY='secretkey'
IP='dhcp'
```

And the permissions of the file:

```
Owner: root
Access: read and write

Group: root
Access: Read-only

Others: read-only

You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions.
```

Comment: You will need to post your profile (with sensitive information removed, naturally) if you want help with this issue. Also, check the permissions on the file...

Comment: It looks OK to me. Try creating another profile with a different name and seeing if you get the same error. Also, make sure you can connect manually.

Comment: Tried creating a new profile and it worked :) Thanks. It seems I had created a directory for a profile instead of a file.

Comment: @SamratManSingh: could you post exactly what you did to resolve this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo netcfg adsl
```

since the owner and group is `root`.